# How to sent email with gmail with Python Flask but not in spam folder?

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to send email with Python Flask but every email from my gmail account is received in the spam folder.
This is my code for send the email :

```
address_list = ['email@test.it']

app = Flask(__name__)
mail= Mail(app)

app.config['MAIL_SERVER']='smtp.gmail.com'
app.config['MAIL_PORT'] = 465
app.config['MAIL_USERNAME'] = 'sender@mail.it'
app.config['MAIL_PASSWORD'] = 'password'
app.config['MAIL_USE_TLS'] = False
app.config['MAIL_USE_SSL'] = True
mail = Mail(app)


def send_async_email(msg):
    with app.app_context():
       mail.send(msg)

for x in address_list:
    msg = Message('Hello', sender = 'sender@mail.it', recipients = [x])
    msg.body = "Hello Flask message sent from Flask-Mail"
    send_async_email(msg)
    print("sent")
```

Is there any way to prevent this from happening? maybe an option to add to make sure that the mails I send are received as normal mails ?

thank you very much

Comment: Try formatting the Email properly and unmark the email from spam a few times

Comment: yes thanks, but I need to send the email to many costumers, so i'm not able to unmark the email from spam

Comment: Gmail is prone to sending your messages to the spam folder when you send many of them or they are similar to other test messages. There is noting you can modify in your code to change their behavior, but you can make sure you don't send too much and that the messages are not too generic.

Comment: Add proper DNS(PTR, SPF & DKIM) records to avoid landing mail as insecure mail

Answer (score 0):

To reduce the chances that messages from your domain are sent to spam or blocked by Gmail, follow the general best practices:

This article is by google team:

> 1. Set up valid reverse DNS records of your IP addresses that point to your domain.
> 2. Ideally, send all messages from the same IP address. If you must send from multiple IP addresses, use different IP addresses for
>    different types of messages. For example, use one IP address for
>    sending account notifications and a different IP address for sending
>    promotional messages.
> 3. Don't mix different types of content in the same messages. For example, don't include content about promotions in purchase receipt
>    messages.
> 4. Messages of the same category should have the same email address in the From: header. For example, messages from a domain called
>    solarmora.com might have From: headers like this: Purchase receipt
>    messages: receipt@solarmora.com Promotional messages:
>    deals@solarmora.com Account notification messages: alert@solarmora.com
>    Check regularly to make sure your domain isn’t listed as unsafe with
>    Google Safe Browsing. To check your domain status, enter your domain
>    in the Safe Browsing site status page. Also check any domain that’s
>    linked to yours.
> 5. Don’t send sample phishing messages or test campaigns from your domain. Your domain’s reputation might be negatively affected, and
>    your domain could be added to internet blocklists. Don’t impersonate
>    other domains or senders without permission. This practice is called
>    spoofing, and it can cause Gmail to mark the messages as spam.
> 6. To help prevent valid messages from being marked as spam: Messages that have a From address in the recipient’s Contacts list are less
>    likely to be marked as spam. Occasionally, valid messages might be
>    marked as spam. Recipients can mark valid messages as not spam, so
>    future messages from the sender should be delivered to their inbox.

[link to google article](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/81126)

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Unfortunately, a mere link to an off-site solution is not an acceptable answer here; at the very least, please summarize what’s behind the link, in case it stops working, or visitors are unable or unwilling to click through. Anyway, this question has been asked and answered here many times before, but then usually closed as off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I send mail using flask and it works, so give it a try

```
from flask_mail import Mail, Message
# This app is: app = Flask(__name__)
from models import app
from config import SendMail

app.config.from_object(SendMail)
mail = Mail(app)


def send_mail():
    msg = Message('Title')
    address = 'receiver_email_id'
    msg.recipients.append(str(address))
    msg.body = "YOUR_MESSAGE"
    mail.send(msg)
```

Config.py

```
class SendMail(object):
    MAIL_SERVER = 'smtp.gmail.com'
    MAIL_PORT = 587
    MAIL_USE_TLS = True
    MAIL_USE_SSL = False
    MAIL_USERNAME = 'sender_email_id'
    MAIL_PASSWORD = 'password'
    MAIL_DEFAULT_SENDER = 'sender_email_id'
    MAIL_MAX_EMAILS = None
    MAIL_ASCII_ATTACHMENTS = False
```